# How to transform code from a tsv import to direct data

Tags: csv, d3.js, svg

I'm working with some D3 examples in php driven pages.  I've found a great example I want to use of a line chart with inline lables (full code here: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4b66c0d9be9a0d56484e), but I can't figure out how to transition the code from a tsv import to an array provided directly from the database.

I am obviously providing the data directly like this:

```
var data = [
{date:2009, Apples:130, Bananas:40},
{date:2010, Apples:137, Bananas:58},
{date:2011, Apples:166, Bananas:97},
{date:2012, Apples:154, Bananas:117},
{date:2013, Apples:179, Bananas:98},
{date:2014, Apples:187, Bananas:120},
{date:2015, Apples:189, Bananas:84}     
]
```

And then I'm trying to replace this chunk of code that handles the import and the sorting into an array automatically.

```
d3.requestTsv("data.tsv", function(d) {
  d.date = parseTime(d.date);
  for (var k in d) if (k !== "date") d[k] = +d[k];
  return d;
}, function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;

  var series = data.columns.slice(1).map(function(key) {
    return data.map(function(d) {
      return {
        key: key,
        date: d.date,
        value: d[key]
      };
    });
  });
```

But I think I'm having problems replicating the portion that creates the series.

I've tried several variations of this:

```
var series = data.map(function(key) {
    return data.map(function(d) {
      return {
        key: key,
        date: d.date,
        value: d[key]
      };
    });
  });
```

followed with a function to set the data type at the end of the code:

```
function type(d) {
  d.date = parseTime(d.date);
  for (var k in d) if (k !== "date") d[k] = +d[k];
  return d;
}
```

But nothing seems to work.  I'm sure there is something simple I'm missing, but what should I specifically be changing here to use code by providing the data directly in an array instead of a tsv import?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data array is correct (regarding the TSV in Bostock's code).

However, you have two problems:

1. The `d3.tsv` function creates an array property named `columns`. Since you're ditching `d3.tsv` and using a variable to store the data, you'll have to create that array yourself:

   ```
   data.columns = ["date", "Apples", "Bananas"]
   ```
2. The `d3.tsv` accepts a row function. Again, since you're using a variable to store the data, you'll have to use a `forEach` to do what the row function does in Bostock's code:

   ```
   data.forEach(d=>{
       d.date = parseTime(d.date);
       for (var k in d) if (k !== "date") d[k] = +d[k];
   });
   ```

Here is the updated code using a **variable** to store the data: https://bl.ocks.org/anonymous/749f2c5bc6a42d68bca3ec579646ff1d

And here the same code in the Stack snippet:

```html
<style>

text {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.line {
  fill: none;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.label {
  text-anchor: middle;
}

.label rect {
  fill: white;
}

.label-key {
  font-weight: bold;
}

</style>
<svg width="960" height="500"></svg>
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v4.0.0-alpha.9.min.js"></script>
<script>

var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%Y");

var svg = d3.select("svg");

var margin = {top: 30, right: 50, bottom: 30, left: 30},
    width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom,
    labelPadding = 3;

var g = svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var data = [
{date:2009, Apples:130, Bananas:40},
{date:2010, Apples:137, Bananas:58},
{date:2011, Apples:166, Bananas:97},
{date:2012, Apples:154, Bananas:117},
{date:2013, Apples:179, Bananas:98},
{date:2014, Apples:187, Bananas:120},
{date:2015, Apples:189, Bananas:84}     
];
  
  data.columns = ["date", "Apples", "Bananas"]
 
  data.forEach(d=>{
    d.date = parseTime(d.date);
  for (var k in d) if (k !== "date") d[k] = +d[k];
  });


  var series = data.columns.slice(1).map(function(key) {
    return data.map(function(d) {
      return {
        key: key,
        date: d.date,
        value: d[key]
      };
    });
  });

  var x = d3.scaleTime()
      .domain([data[0].date, data[data.length - 1].date])
      .range([0, width]);

  var y = d3.scaleLinear()
      .domain([0, d3.max(series, function(s) { return d3.max(s, function(d) { return d.value; }); })])
      .range([height, 0]);

  var z = d3.scaleCategory10();

  g.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

  var serie = g.selectAll(".serie")
      .data(series)
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "serie");

  serie.append("path")
      .attr("class", "line")
      .style("stroke", function(d) { return z(d[0].key); })
      .attr("d", d3.line()
          .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
          .y(function(d) { return y(d.value); }));

  var label = serie.selectAll(".label")
      .data(function(d) { return d; })
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "label")
      .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(" + x(d.date) + "," + y(d.value) + ")"; });

  label.append("text")
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .text(function(d) { return d.value; })
    .filter(function(d, i) { return i === data.length - 1; })
    .append("tspan")
      .attr("class", "label-key")
      .text(function(d) { return " " + d.key; });

  label.append("rect", "text")
      .datum(function() { return this.nextSibling.getBBox(); })
      .attr("x", function(d) { return d.x - labelPadding; })
      .attr("y", function(d) { return d.y - labelPadding; })
      .attr("width", function(d) { return d.width + 2 * labelPadding; })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return d.height + 2 * labelPadding; });

</script>
```